# How to configure multiple Jersey provider packages using javax dynamic servlet registration

Tags: java, servlets, jersey

I am using [`javax.servlet.Registration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Registration.Dynamic.html) to dynamically configure/register servlets.

I'd like to know how I could configure multiple provider packages for `Jersey`. I can add a single package using the `setInitParamater` method as follows:

```
public class MyWebInitalization implements WebApplicationInitializer {

  @Override
  public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    //... some code
    final ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", ServletContainer.class);
    dispatcher.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", "com.package1"); // how to add more packages?
    //... more code
  }
}
```

To give you an idea of what I mean, this is an equivalent if I would have used web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    ...
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.package1;com.package2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    ...
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you try something like this `dispatcher.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", "com.package1;com.package2");` ?

Comment: Works like a charm. Why didn't I think of that before. I am probably getting old :) Thanks man.